# Add a number to a column if it's equal to another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two integer columns in a df that looks like these:

```
ColA   ColB
71829  81734
73246  54613
94618  94618
91263  71736
93713  93713
32728  91283
```

So If the value of ColA == ColB I have to add one number to ColA

I tried with the below code but it didn't work

```
Col['A'] = [Col['A'] + 1  if Col['A'] == Col['B'] else Col['A'] for x in Col['A']]

Expected output:
ColA   ColB
71829  81734
73246  54613
**94619  94618**
91263  71736
**93714  93713**
32728  91283
```

So, Do you know how can I get the expected output?

Comment: I notice people always get more help when they provide the code to get started.  If you give the `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` code you might get help faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean series, and use to add 1 since True is equal to 1:

```
df['ColA'] += (df['ColA'] == df['ColB'])

#Out[66]: 
#     ColA   ColB
# 0  71829  81734
# 1  73246  54613
# 2  94619  94618
# 3  91263  71736
# 4  93714  93713
# 5  32728  91283
```

If you would like to add more than 1, e.g. 3 you can use it like this:

```
df['ColA'] += (df['ColA'] == df['ColB']) * 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over each row of the dataframe, something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = [1,2,3]
df['B'] = [3,2,1]


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == row['B']:
        row['A'] +=1
        
print(df)
```